# Can't run python file from DOS shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Using: Python 3.6 on windows 10

I've built a very simple program called `pythontest.py`:

```
a = 1 
print('the value of a is ', a)
```

I've saved it as a .py file. When I try to run it from the terminal it returns the following:

```
C:\Users\jona_>python pythontest.py
  File "pythontest.py", line 1
    Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've checked whether the path is correct a multitude of times, and even when I drag the file from file-explorer into the command line it still returns this syntax error. I've tried other pre-made files that came with the xlsxwriter library and they don't return this error. This probably means something is wrong with the file but I can't for the life of me understand what.

Comment: Open `pythontest.py` in a code editor like Sublime or Notepad++. Is what you put in the question the *only* contents of the file, or is there something else?

Comment: I would suggest that you install [IPython](https://ipython.org/). It is a wonderfull environment for using Python interactively. And as hansaplast suggest, read some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I'm new to the platform so apologies if I didn't exactly abide by the code of conduct. I'll try and do better tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that this is the first line of `pythontest.py:`:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Open your file in an editor an remove this line.
The only content in the file should be the two lines you show in your question.